# NetBeans 7.3 maven project "No web folder found"

Tags: maven, netbeans, web, directory

I am running the latest version of NetBeans (7.3) with GlassFish and I have created a maven web project that adds the necessary JSF 2.1 dependency. I am able to deploy the project and access the home page. The problem is that when I try to use the "JSF pages from Entities" wizard, I get the following error "No web folder found". If I try to add the JSF 2.1 framework support thru "Project/Properties/Framework" I get the same error.
 I assume that NetBeans does not know that a "web folder" already exists but at a different location "project/src/main/webapp" (maven) instead of "project/web" as it normally expects if the project is a non-maven project. Does anybody know if there is a setting I can change, to let NetBeans know that the web folder is located under "project/src/main/webapp" instead of "project/web"?
 I tried to get support thru the NetBeans forum/mailing-list but nobody responded.

Comment: Well it started working after a while. I have no idea why it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to import an eclipse project.

After editing the "nbproject/project.properties" manually, changing the build.web.dir property to the right directory (WebContent instead of web) it seemed to work.